# do in zsh a for loop with if-statement

Tags: loops, for-loop, if-statement, zsh

I'm writing my own package manager for vim / zsh / tmux

Now I want to check if the repo is already there before try to download

I got the function to clone the repo from github

```
function zsh_add_plugin() {
  PLUGIN_NAME=$(echo $1 | cut -d "/" -f 2)
  git clone "https://github.com/$1.git" "$ZDOTDIR/$PLUGIN_NAME"
}
```

and I got a list with the plugins

```
zsh_plugins=(
  'hlissner/zsh-autopair'
  'zsh-users/zsh-completions'
  'romkatv/powerlevel10k'
  'zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting'
  'zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions'
  'zsh-users/zsh-completions'
)
```

I could do now

```
for i in $zsh_plugins;
  do zsh_add_plugin $i;
done
```

but I would like to check if it's already available

I tried like this but withoud success

```
for i in $zsh_plugins;

   if [ ! -d "'$ZDOTDIR'/'$i'" ]; then

      do zsh_add_plugin $i;

   fi

done
```

getting this error

```
zsh: parse error near `zsh_add_plugin'
```

I hope someone could help

---

I tried also like that

```
for i in $zsh_plugins
   do

      if [ ! -d "$ZDOTDIR/$i" ]; then

      zsh_add_plugin $i;

      fi

done
```

I'ts not working properly.

The loop doesnt check if the repo is available

and im getting the errors

```
fatal: destination path '.....' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Comment: Get rid of the single quotes in your `[` expression.

Comment: 2nd question: "the directory exists and it's not empty", if it's not empty there's no much you can do other than printing the error and exiting

Comment: The function should check the repository and skip the `i` if its not empty. Is something like that possible?
The result should be without errors

Answer (score 0):

Move the `do` to the `for` loop

```
for i in $zsh_plugins
do

   if [ ! -d "'$ZDOTDIR'/'$i'" ]; then

      zsh_add_plugin $i;

   fi

done
```

Comment: unfortunately no :/ 
still geht the error `fatal: destination path '/Users/user/.zsh_plugins/zsh-autopair' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Comment: That's another, unrelated error. Please post a new question if you have follow-up questions.